# Example on how to use JetBrains' MPS with Maven?

Tags: maven, mps

I'm currently playing around with JetBrains' MPS. While the documentation lists a few examples on how to create IntelliJ plugins from your custom languages (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD31/Building+IntelliJ+IDEA+language+plugins), I fail to find an example how you could incorporate your custom language in a Maven build. Does anyone know whether or not this is possible and if it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM, you can only use MPS languages in Ant builds through the provided set of Ant tasks.

Comment: @Vaclav is there maven plugin in plans?

Comment: @AskarKalykov I have a raw prototype ready which I'll try to put up on GitHub as soon as possible. It requires MPS 3.3 or later though.

Comment: @SergejKoščejev that would be nice to have!

Comment: @AskarKalykov the early prototype is now on GitHub, at https://github.com/jetbrains/mps-maven-deployer and https://github.com/jetbrains/mps-maven-plugin. It's probably not generally usable at this point but I'm working on it and would appreciate any feedback and ideas.

Comment: @SergejKoščejev is the plugin in use? It is in preview for quite a while, and it's really hard to kick off MPS usage in development process while it has poor tooling support. How do you use MPS and CI inside Jetbrains?

Comment: @AskarKalykov I don't think it's in use. The best way of using Maven with MPS is to have MPS generate the Ant files and call them from Maven using maven-antrun-plugin.

I wouldn't look at JetBrains for inspiration about CI practices, development of MPS itself is quite different from developing products based on MPS.